# Conditionally adding .Take()

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Currently I have this that automatically takes 500 rows:

```
var orderQuery = subsetTable.Where(pred).OrderByDescending(o => o.CreationDate).Take(500);
```

I'd like to make the Take() conditional, something like this:

```
var orderQuery = subsetTable.Where(pred).OrderByDescending(o => o.CreationDate);
if (condition)
    orderQuery = orderQuery.Take(500);
```

Is this possible?

Edit:
The compiler says

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'."

Comment: What did your compiler tell you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add "AsQueryable" to make the types line up:

```
var orderQuery = subsetTable.Where(pred).OrderByDescending(o => o.CreationDate).AsQueryable();
if (condition)
    orderQuery = orderQuery.Take(500);
```

Comment: I used this to maintain the use of var.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 12):

In Linq-to-Objects, the `var` will infer to `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is the type of your object. The `Take()` will yield an `IEnumerable<T>`, so your line of code there will not be allowed. (IOrderedEnumerable is more specified than IEnumerable, you need your query to typed in a less-specified manner.) And, as the comments point out, the same holds true for providers that deal in terms of `IQueryable<T>`, which itself can be expressed as a less specified `IEnumerable<T>`.

To make it work, explicitly type your query to the lesser specified type you need, `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`, and then you can apply your conditional `Take`.

```
IEnumerable<YourType> orderedQuery = ...
if (condition)
     orderedQuery = orderedQuery.Take(n);
```

Comment: +1 And in linq to SQL/entities/NHibernate replace `IEnumerable` by `IQueryable` and the same is true.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this possible?

Yes.  Your code should work nearly as written.  You just have to eliminate the `var`.  Assuming your type is `Order`. you'd use:

```
IQueryable<Order> orderQuery = subsetTable.Where(pred).OrderByDescending(o => o.CreationDate);
if (condition)
    orderQuery = orderQuery.Take(500);
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think it would because of the `var` inferring to `IOrderedEnumerable<>` in the first statement, and `Take` yielding `IEnumerable<>` in the second.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram True - fixed.

Answer (score -2):

What I do is to add Sorting at the end, to avoid having to convert them

```
var orderQuery = subsetTable.Where(pred);

if (condition)
    orderQuery = orderQuery.Take(500);

orderQuery = orderQuery.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreationDate);
```

Comment: This changes the behavior, since you're only sorting the first 500 elements, not taking the first 500 sorted elements.

Comment: No, the `.Take(500)` will be applied when you execute the query. In `.List();` for example

Comment: Yes - the Take is executed when you query, but the Take is interpreted to mean Take the results, then sort, where the original was sort, then take (on the server).

Comment: The OrderBy definitely needs to be before the Take(). This code will almost certainly introduce bugs.